# How to access subversion repository?

Tags: svn

I am new to subversion, my company has a subversion repository, they have granted me access,but i don't no how to access it ? Is there anyway that I can access subversion repository through git ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the address of the repository from someone at your company then download a SVN client like SmartSVN or TortoiseSVN. Either of these will prompt you with a window asking for an address and a repository name as well as some credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** to have URL of repository, username and password

Yes, you can access Subversion repository with Git, just try to [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) about Git-SVN

- [git-svn Man Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)
- [Git and Subversion](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) in Git-Book
- Short [git-svn-tutorial](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial)